# Is there a way to mass seperate ligands from molecule structure in Pymol?

Tags: python, scripting, pymol

I have over 100+ pdb files uploaded on PyMOL and my task is to perform some analysis on them. Everything was going smoothly until I was asked to take the ligands for each structure and highlight and represent them as a selected object which I can use for further analysis.

Doing it manually, you would click on the sequence viewer where you can select all of the ligands on the molecule. However, I need to do this for over 100+ structures so is there a way I can automate the task?
I looked through the documentation and tried several different approaches involving selection algebra but nothing seemed to work so far. Could someone experienced in PyMOL help me out?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: PyMOL has a command line where you can write short scripts such as "align [protein]" or "show surface". That is essentially the "code".